# Can I set a variable globally inside freeswitch. Then invoke and update it upon initiating each sip session call.Access and use the variable anytime

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-handling, global-variables, freeswitch

I need to know if I can use a variable globally inside freeswitch. after give a fresh start of freeswitch server , I want a variable,that will be assigned a specific value and that value will get incremented upon each execution of a dialplan.I am trying to keep count of my each sip session with a var and want to access it any time as per my need.

this is a part of my default.xml dialplan.

```
<extension name="lua_script_example">
      <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(100[0-9]|101[0-9])$">
        <!-- Set custom channel variables with dynamic input -->
        <action application="set" data="input_a=5"/>
        <action application="set" data="input_b=7"/>
        <action application="set" data="caller_id_number=${caller_id_number}"/>
        <action application="set" data="call_session_count=${call_session_count}"/>
        <action application="javascript" data="myjscript.js"/>
      </condition>
    </extension>
```

this is a part of my vars.xml file.

```
<include>

<X-PRE-PROCESS cmd="set" data="call_session_count=0"/>

</include>
```

this is myjscript.js file of scripts folder inside freeswitch

```
// Get dynamic input from channel variables
const input_a = parseInt(session.getVariable("input_a"));
const input_b = parseInt(session.getVariable("input_b"));
let input_c = parseInt(session.getVariable("call_session_count"));

if (!isNaN(destination_number_int) && destination_number_int >= 1000 && destination_number_int <= 1019) {
    

    // Get caller and receiver information
    const caller = session.getVariable("caller_id_number");
    const receiver = session.getVariable("destination_number");
    input_c = input_c+1;
    session.setVariable("call_session_count", input_c);
            console_log("info", "Caller: " + caller + "\n");
            console_log("info", "Receiver: " + receiver + "\n");
            console_log("info", "Call session number: " + input_c + "\n");

}
session.answer();
// Dial the destination number
session.execute("bridge", "user/" + destination_number);
```

Now, in the vars.xml i was assigning a variable and then in the default.xml dialplan i was passing that variable inside a js script "myjscript.js". later this script will execute and increment the value by 1 and then set the varibale value with the new value and printed it to confirm with the updated value in the fs_cli.

this dialplan section will execute in each initiated call , so as the script. i was hoping that it will get incremented . but it is remaining same and i got the below response:
[fs_cli response session 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmcOe.png)[fs_cli response session 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ9ki.png)

Yes , I could use event socket library (for js it is modesl). and ,i implemented it also. but my project lead told me that it will take more time to load balance when thousands of call will run concurrently, if he needs to get the variable from event socket. the variable should be in the shared memory or, something like this. no database or esl. so that he can grab it in no time when need.

please give me a possible idea to solve it.Thanks everyone.